# Git list of changed files has been wiped

Tags: git, upgrade, changeset

So I was working on a project when Windows 10 decided to update to 1607. I had saved all my work but not committed some 22 changed files.

After the update and re-installation of IIS, I have opened my project again and Git is reporting I have no changed files. I can see the work I have done. it's not rolled anything back, I've lost no work, but I can't commit what I have done, as apparently there are no changes.

How can I ask Git to check the files for changes against the branch?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. (with Git obviously)

Comment: Step 1) Use a real git client instead of the VS2015 thing

Comment: I also have GitKraken installed, at first it didn't think I had anything in my repo, but then from the file menu I selected the same repo again and now it's found everything. But I can't tell if it has my changes or it's just listing the last checkin's changes, yet to be pushed.

Comment: Yeah, apart from getting a bit confused over what was in teh repo GitKracken has identified and checked in the appropriate files.

Comment: Step 2) stop using Windows so you can control your computer ;)

Comment: Maybe you can find out what happened in your `git reflog`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason since upgrading to 1607, and subsequently flattening the PC and reinstalling Windows 10 1607, there is a .jfm file in a SQL project that devenv won't let go of, so I get file access issues everywhere.

As soon as I add this file extension to .gitignore everything returned to normal.